# webform blank page D7

Tags: webforms

The Webform module is installed. I go to /admin/content/webform to build new form, but the page is completely blank. The content is empty. What am I missing? Is there an additional library I need?

I do have Views and Chaos Tools installed. And my administrator role has permission to modify webforms.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Check any log you have. We don't have access to them, and we cannot guess what the problem is, since guessing is not the purpose of Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Webform issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2484017) which might be similar to this question here. Though that issue is after "upgrading", one could argue that after "upgrade" or after "install" of the module, the result is in both cases that you are using the newest version of the module, right?

So therefore, here are a few things in that issue that might help to get you going:

- **Clear the cache** and try again.
- if you did something like an update of that module (I think not, but you never know), then **run update.php** and try again.
- Try to **disable and then enable** the module, and try again.

Curious to hear if any of this helps ...

Comment: I updates the module to 4.8 ran update and disabled enabled. Nothing yet. I'll update as I play around.